# Return new object from filtering deeply nested array of object

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I understand that questions like this have been asked so many times but unfortunately I did not get any success even after trying many solutions for long time. I have deeply nested array of objects like following which I would like to filter :

```
[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "tags": [
        {
          "sys": {
            "id": "product"
          }
        },
        {
          "sys": {
            "id": "tech"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "fields": {
      "title": "About Geography",
      "path": "about-geo"
    }
  },
  {
    "metadata": {
      "tags": [
        {
          "sys": {
            "id": "product"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "fields": {
      "title": "Explore",
      "path": "exp"
    }
  }
]
```

I am able to filter the object for ids in `posts.metadata.tags.sys.id` using following :

```
const result = posts.map(post => post.metadata.tags.filter( tag=> tag.sys.id.includes('tech')))

// expected output

[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "tags": [
        {
          "sys": {
            "id": "product"
          }
        },
        {
          "sys": {
            "id": "tech"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "fields": {
      "title": "About Geography",
      "path": "about-geo"
    }
  }
]
```

The filtering works but I am not able to get returned object in expected output. I want the returned object to be exactly same as main object but just with the matching `posts.metadata.tags.sys.id` , which is "tech" in this example. So the returned object must return only first object.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you're mapping `posts`, so you're going to get an array back w/ the results of the `filter`, which is also an array. If you don't want a `map` then just iterate (or reduce). It might be helpful to include the explicit result you're looking for, I don't quite get what you're asking for yet.

Comment: I have added expected output that I want the JS code to return. May be I am doing it worng by using `map` function.

Comment: One way might be to `filter` instead of `map` and check for the result array having > 0 length, e.g., `posts.filter(post => post.metadata.tags.filter( tag=> tag.sys.id.includes('tech')).length > 0)`

Comment: (Noting that this doesn't return a "new" object (nor does the original snippet), it returns a reference to the existing object. Returning a *new* object would require a deep copy.)